# How check which variable is greater in xsl?

Tags: xslt

```
   <xsl:variable name="a">20</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="b">10</xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="($a) > ($b)">
        ------
  </xsl:if>
```

I getting error in the if condion..

Comment: Looks fine to me. Neither libxslt nor Transformiix display an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following :

```
 <xsl:if test="$a &gt; $b">
```

Try using the character entities for > (&gt;) and < (&lt;) operators in expressions, otherwise *some* parsers think you are closing the tag early, or opening another.

Comment: You don't have to escape `>`. It is absolutely possible to use `$a > $b`.

Comment: You're right, the XSLT parser I used many moons ago got me in the practice of escaping them to avoid parser errors. Just checked now and your code works fine. I learn something new every day, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The example you posted should work. However, you should not that in your case both variables are of type string which could give surprising results where their length differs. The behaviour of the comparison operator on different datatypes is specified in the [xpath spec on booleans](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans).

To avoid this you could declare the variables using the `select` attribute or manually convert them to [number](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number) for the comparison:

```
<xsl:variable name="a" select="20"/>
<xsl:variable name="b" select="10"/>
...
<xsl:if test="number($a) > number($b)">
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: "When neither object to be compared is a node-set and the operator is <=, <, >= or >, then the objects are compared by converting both objects to numbers and comparing the numbers according to IEEE 754." - No undefined behavior.

Comment: @Saxoier: You are right, the paragraph preceding your quote only applied to operators `=` and `!=`.