# IF on xlst not working

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, logic

I've been bashing my head against a wall for the last hour trying to figure out why the if is not working, I need a fresh set of eyes to tell me what I am missing on the logic. The if starts just after line 25. It shoudl work, honestly it follows the example in: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_if  But it does nothing!

Please look bellow:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
 <!-- Background image -->
      <body background="bgimage.jpg">
  
        <h2 style="color:#47B2B2">My Movie Collection</h2>
        <!-- set border, color, and padding-->
        <table border="1" bgcolor="#0A1A1A" cellpadding="5">
          <tr bgcolor="#1F4C4C">
    <!-- Set order -->
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director</th>
   <th>Year</th>
   <th>Genre</th>
   <th>ID</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
    <!-- Sort by title -->
            <xsl:sort select="title"/>
   <xsl:if test="year>2005">
            <tr bgcolor="#3D9999">
   
     <td>
      <!-- Look for link, target to blank, the link text is the tittle pulled from xml -->
                <a href="{link}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a>
              </td>
     
              <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="director"/>
     </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
              </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
              </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="movieID"/>
              </td>
    </tr>
   <xsl:if/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need a better testing tool, one that would tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @michael.hor257k which one do you recommend?

Comment: It depends on your needs and platform. At minimum, use a decent online tool such as http://xsltransform.net/

Comment: @michael.hor257k followed the advice it says: Error at xsl:sort on line 26 column 33 
  XTSE0010: An xsl:if element must not contain an xsl:sort element

Comment: In the stylesheet you have posted, xsl:sort is (correctly) the first child of xsl:for-each - so the problem you describe does not occur.

Comment: @michael.hor257k did some changes after, and saw it then corrected, it all works now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsl:if/>` should be a `</xsl:if>` as it is a closing tag not a self-referencing one.

Here would be the corrected code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
 <!-- Background image -->
      <body background="bgimage.jpg">
  
        <h2 style="color:#47B2B2">My Movie Collection</h2>
        <!-- set border, color, and padding-->
        <table border="1" bgcolor="#0A1A1A" cellpadding="5">
          <tr bgcolor="#1F4C4C">
    <!-- Set order -->
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director</th>
   <th>Year</th>
   <th>Genre</th>
   <th>ID</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
    <!-- Sort by title -->
            <xsl:sort select="title"/>
   <xsl:if test="year &gt; 2005">
            <tr bgcolor="#3D9999">
   
     <td>
      <!-- Look for link, target to blank, the link text is the tittle pulled from xml -->
                <a href="{link}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a>
              </td>
     
              <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="director"/>
     </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
              </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
              </td>
     
     <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="movieID"/>
              </td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `<xsl:if test="year>2005">`. The only problem is the self-closing `<xsl:if/>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have tried the test core from w3 in my computer, it needs the closing if

Comment: @user3541786 It needs a closing `</xsl:if>`, not a **self-closing** `<xsl:if/>` which is short for `<xsl:if></xsl:if>` (an empty `xsl:if` element). The way you have it now, you have an opening `<xsl:if>` tag which is never closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097550/how-check-which-variable-is-greater-in-xsl would support my case.

Comment: @michael.hor257k True, I tried </xsl:if> it still does nothing.

Comment: @JBKing What would support your case is an example where using `>` for comparison fails and replacing it with `&gt;` succeeds. Without this, all you have is a preference.

Comment: @user3541786 It does nothing if you're testing it against the input you have linked to. Because `<xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">` selects nothing when the input has `catalog/cd`.

Comment: Found the error: Error at xsl:sort on line 26 column 33 
  XTSE0010: An xsl:if element must not contain an xsl:sort element How to correct?

Comment: Nevermind, just moved it under the sort and it works! Thank you all, specially @michael.hor257k for his suggestion to use xsltransform.net